# SIFT feature Complexity :implementation matlab

Tags: complexity-theory, sift

the complexity of SIFT feature extraction algorithm by Lowe
is their any web or something from where i can get it.
i think it is =>l.m ....where l is number of octaves and m is number of images in it.
want to make it comfirm... is it correct or not? 
: need help in this regard

Comment: Is this really related to MatLAB?